# Is it worth using Perl CGI::Fast on Apache 2?

Tags: perl, apache, fastcgi

I know this sound like a question for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) but I know that developers often get the blame when servers are struggling so I thought a post here might be useful to people who still use [Perl](http://perl.org) on the web.

### THE STORY:

We had serious issues with defunct processes on our old Apache server so we decided to move to Apache 2. The new server performs much better, no denying that. Tests reveal however, that under a heavy load (~100 users per minute) defunct processes start quickly ramping up on the server and using SSH it is clear that these processes are using the CPU. To overcome these issues we decided to implement [CGI::Fast](http://p3rl.org/CGI::Fast) which is a type of [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com) in [Perl](http://perl.org). Having that in place the zombies are gone, however performance wise the server is not coping any better.

The results led me to assume that there isn't really a point implementing [CGI::Fast](http://p3rl.org/CGI::Fast) if Apache 2 will efficiently reclaim the resources anyway.

Does any of you have come to a different conlusion?

Comment: What are you talking about *still*. There are plenty of **NEW** websites being created in Perl. [The Lacuna Expanse](http://lacunaexpanse.com) for example.

Comment: I am saying that Perl is not as widely used as 10-15 years ago, which is a fact. The new generation of programmers coming out of schools today hardly even know that Perl exists. There are more popular languages now such as Ruby and .NET. I am not saying that Perl is "bad" it is just going out of fashion...that is all. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion it’s not worth moving to anything but a [PSGI/Plack](http://plackperl.org)-based solution in 2011, independent of any other details you mentioned.

- The [Plack ecosystem is so much greater](http://www.slideshare.net/ranguard/plack-basics-for-perl-websites-yapceu-2011) than FastCGI’s. (advantage)
- You can deploy to many more servers than [FastCGI supports](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/3). (advantage)
- You may run CGI scripts unmodified with e.g. [Plack::App::CGIBin](http://p3rl.org/Plack::App::CGIBin) whereas CGI::Fast requires a rewrite. (advantage)
- Rewriting a CGI program to conform to the [PSGInterface](http://p3rl.org/PSGI) requires slightly more effort than rewriting it to CGI::Fast. (disadvantage)

Comment: Thanks daxim! This is really interesting and I will definitely give it a shot.

Answer (score 4):

FastCGI is faster than plain CGI because Apache doesn't have to load perl for each new request.  However, the scripts need to be reworked to remove the assumption that they are executed once for each request.  A FastCGI script at its core typically represents some type of event loop, processing the requests as they come in.

You can use CGI::Fast for plain CGI scripts without reworking the script around an event loop, but you lose the "Fast" part of FastCGI this way, as perl still needs to be run once for every script.

FastCGI also only provides a large benefit if the biggest part of your CGI script is loading perl or executing one-time code.  For many web applications, this is true.  However, if your script needs to do a lot of work for each request, such that the overhead of loading perl is small, then you won't see a big performance benefit by using FastCGI.

Comment: In our case the test scenario was simple; using CGI::Fast we established a connection to MySQL outside the loop while inside we worked with the values that the query returned and compared this to a normal CGI script doing the same but without a CGI::Fast loop. Our test revealed that the CGI::Fast loop does give us an edge by being persistent and serving the individual requests working through the same connection. As you say the problem is with the "worked with the values" part that tends to be big in some of these cases... I guess we will have to rethink the way these scripts work :)

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  Good luck with finding the real bottleneck in the code.

Answer (score 1):

**CGI**

It was too inefficient for anything but small sites. CGI spawns a new process for every incoming request to execute a script, a very resource intensive and inefficient way of doing things. No wonder it faded away over time as web applications became more complex.

**FastCGI** was introduced to avoid some of the issues with running languages inside the Apache process, as well as avoiding the inefficiency of CGI.

A FastCGI application is executed outside of the web server (Apache or other wise), and waits for requests from the web server using a socket. The web server and the FastCGI application can even be on separate physical machines and communicate over the network.

Because the web server adn the application processes are separate better isolation is possible.

Comment: In this case my question was really about CGI::Fast that is an extension on CGI. CGI::Fast is persistent so it should not spawn a new process for every request. FastCGI support we don't have on our server so it is out of the question at the moment.